# Failed to apply plugin class 'org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin'. gradle-plugins-7.4.2.jar (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, linux, gradle, centos, qupath

I am following the [instructions for building QuPath](https://qupath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/reference/building.html) from source on CentOS 7. I get the following error:

```
[jalal@goku qupath]$ ./gradlew clean jpackage

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to apply plugin class 'org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /scratch3/downloads/gradle-7.4.2/lib/plugins/gradle-plugins-7.4.2.jar (No such file or directory)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 721ms
```

The instructions that I am following are as follows:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/qupath/qupath
$ cd qupath
$ ./gradlew clean jpackage
```

I have:

```
$ uname -a
Linux goku.bu.edu 3.10.0-1160.59.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 23 16:47:03 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
Release:    7.9.2009
Codename:   Core
```

also:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_322"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_322-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.322-b06, mixed mode)
```

I also don't understand why it is looking elsewhere than where I have zipped it and set the directory to it as in:

```
[jalal@goku downloads]$ sudo vi  /etc/profile.d/gradle.sh
[jalal@goku downloads]$ sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/gradle.sh
[jalal@goku downloads]$ source /etc/profile.d/gradle.sh
[jalal@goku downloads]$ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.4.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-03-31 15:25:29 UTC
Revision:     540473b8118064efcc264694cbcaa4b677f61041

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          1.8.0_322 (Red Hat, Inc. 25.322-b06)
OS:           Linux 3.10.0-1160.59.1.el7.x86_64 amd64

[jalal@goku downloads]$ cat /etc/profile.d/gradle.sh 

export GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle/gradle-7.4.2
export PATH=${GRADLE_HOME}/bin:${PATH}

$ tail -1 ~/.bashrc
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-7.4.2/bin
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

The plugin that is reported as missing in the error is in

```
[jalal@goku ~]$ find /opt/gradle -name "gradle-plugins-7.4.2.jar"
/opt/gradle/gradle-7.4.2/lib/plugins/gradle-plugins-7.4.2.jar
```

Full log of `./gradlew clean jpackage --stacktrace`: https://pastebin.com/raw/RuuJnuTe

Full log of `./gradlew clean jpackage --debug`:
https://pastebin.com/raw/EPJs2jRR

Full log of `./gradlew clean jpackage --scan`:
https://pastebin.com/raw/TUGSM73K

Comment: Instead of using the `gradlew` script, try to install Gradle manually and run `gradle` instead: https://gradle.org/install/

Comment: @SamuelAudet your comment is not very clear to me. All of the above steps are from the manual provided by QuPath and gradle. Could you provide step by step guide on what you mentioned?

Comment: also, I have installed gradle manually from source into /opt/gradle as you see in my question description

Comment: @SamuelAudet is this what you meant? `[jalal@goku qupath]$ ./gradle clean jpackage
bash: ./gradle: Is a directory`

Comment: \gradlew is a wrapper over gradle to make the use of gradle easier. Here in your case it seems that the gradle version inside /scratch3/downloads directory is missing some plugin file that is required. I think if you find and copy the required file inside the directory it will do the trick.

Comment: @MehdiGolzadeh there is no gradle installed in `[jalal@goku downloads]$ pwd
/scratch3/downloads
[jalal@goku downloads]$ find . -name "*gradle*"
./gradle-7.4.2-all.zip` as I mentioned in OP, I installed the gradle following the original instructions in `/opt/gradle`